# Regular expression for matching texts before and after string

Tags: java, regex

I would like to match URL strings which can be specified in the following manner.
*xxx*.yyy.com (For example, the regular expression should match all strings like 4xxx.yyy.com, xxx4.yyy.com, xxx.yyy.com, 4xxx4.yyy.com, 444xxx666.yyy.com, abcxxxdef.yyy.com etc).

I have tried to use

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+$)xxx([a-zA-Z0-9]+$).yyy.com

([a-zA-Z0-9]*)xxx([a-zA-Z0-9]*).yyy.com
```

But they don't work. Please help me write a correct regular expression. Thanks in advance.

Note: I'm trying to do this in Java.

Comment: Please try `(?:\d+)?xxx(?:\d+)?\.yyy\.com`. Please see demo [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/wK9MQ1/11) or `(?:\d*)xxx(?:\d*)\.yyy\.com`

Comment: I think you need to escape the period if you intend to match it. As the pattern is written now, it will not work.

Comment: @Mandy8055 thanks for the response. I would like to match digits, characters and special characters as well. I think \d+ will match only digits. Sorry I have edited my question.

Comment: I updated @NaveenBharadwaj; please see the above comment. Or if you don't want only white-spaces use `\S*xxx\S*\.yyy\.com`. Please do let me know if it helped.

Comment: Would you need regex? What about an `if` construct: `if (Str.endsWith(".yyy.com") && Str.contains("xxx")) {.....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make sure there is *xxx* and you want to allow all non whitespace chars before and after. If you want to match the whole string, you could add anchors at the start and end.

Note to escape the dot to match it literally.

```
^\S*xxx\S*\.yyy\.com$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\S*xxx\S*` Match xxx between optional non whitespace chars
- `\.yyy` Match *.yyy*
- `\.com` Match *.com*
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zDY2h4/1)

In Java double escape the backslash

```
String regex = "^\\S*xxx\\S*\\.yyy\\.com$";
```

---

Or specify the characters on the left and right that you would allow to match in the character class:

```
^[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%^&*()_+]*xxx[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%^&*()_+]*\.yyy\.com$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N3zDD5/1)